# overflow-x is causing scroll bars on main window as well as in the div

Tags: css, overflow

I have a div that I want to have side scrolling in. It takes up 100% of the screen width. The div is working how it should be, but I don't want side-scrolling enabled in the window. I have tried adding overflow: hidden; to the parent element but this doesn't fix the issue. I have put a red border around the HTML element in the developer window, and according to it, there is nothing that wide.

[image]

any help on how to troubleshoot this or suggestion on what I could do? There is a ton of code on the site, so it is hard to pull just the relevant bits. but if there is something you think I should add let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to snip the code down to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue; in other words, a [mcve]. Anyway, is your screenshot supposed to show what goes wrong? There aren't any scrollbars in it.

Comment: ok working on pulling that and cleaning it up now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just answering so that this thread gets closed.

I shouldn't have asked here, it was too much code to comb through and was a matter of on absolute position item inside the scrolling divs.

I am confused why the html border wasn't expanded but the webpage was, but I'll just chalk it up to a quirk for now.